# Where is location of AC pressure sensor on 2007 Buick Lacrosse?

Tags: ac, sensor, buick, replace, lacrosse

I will replace the AC pressure sensor/pressure switch on my 2007 Buick lacrosse. I don't have lots of experience but I am learning. I recently changed the oil, flushed the coolant, replaced the thermostat and never had any problems. I know some people will say if you can't even locate don't get involved but I looked everywhere and I couldn't locate it. Where is it?
Thank you

Comment: Do you have an issue with the air conditioning?

Comment: When I try to turn on AC I see the light come on but it doesn't give me cold air. I checked and saw that the clutch doesn't get engaged. I recently did ac recharge and when I bypass AC compressor AC works perfectly. I left it on for like 15 min and it was giving me ice cold air. So we know air compressor works just fine. I also checked the relay and put it different fuse it didn't change anything.

Comment: How did you do the electrical bypass?  Did you check voltages at the a/c cpmpressor relay?

Comment: By paperclip on the relay of ac compressor then ac started again.No I didn't check voltages

Comment: So I replaced the ac pressure switch but my problem still exists, any other ideas? pressure switch was right under the air filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone, the problem has solved. It was the low ac pressure switch, not high-pressure switch.